# Data structure to be used for implementing online booking system

Tags: data-structures

It was asked by a interviewer.

The target is to Design a train tickets Reservation system. If the train go through 5 stations(e.g. A,B,C,D,E). We could sell tickets from A-E or A-B, if a ticket from A-B is sold, we could go on sell tickets between B-E.

The question is which data structure is suitable to present the seats? It should show which section is available for sale.

Thanks for help!

Comment: I don't know why people vote down on this ,but I am a serious user and ready to accept any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be quite honest, "that interviewer's question, at least as it has been presented by you, makes very little *sense.*"  (Maybe the interviewer provided more details at-the-time that you have since forgotten.)

But the basic idea should be: "what is the *fact* that you need to represent?"  Well, in this case, the "fact" is that `user_X`, on `this_train`, has a `ticket` to go `from_station` A, `to_station` B ... where "A" and "B" are *enumerations* such that you can easily determine when two stations "overlap."

From this, you can then proceed to define the various "bright-line rules" that the reservation system must be able to apply.  For instance:  "how many existing reservations *overlap* a certain range-of-stops?"  (This will allow you to determine if the seat-capacity of the train would be exceeded.)

Comment: thanks for your help. maybe it is not a good question, but I was tring to give all details I could. Though there is  a  vote down function, but I don't think it should be used here.